# creating a conditional column based on multiple column criteria (R)

Tags: r, if-statement

```
TowQty <- c(2,3,4,5,9,0,0,0,4);
SvcQty<- c(4,8,3,4,2,0,,4,0,2);
Acc.AvgTowInv<- c(20,25,65,45,67,0,0,0,76);
Acc.AvgSvcInv<-c(25,32,45,53,23,0,26,0,43)

data.frame <- data.frame(TowQty , SvcQty, Acc.AvgTowInv, Acc.AvgSvcInv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

? Creating New Conditional_Column based on criteria below)

when (TowQty > 0 and SvcQty > 0) then (((1 - ((Acc.AvgTowInv - 50.0) / 50.0)) * 40) + ((1 - ((Acc.AvgSvcInv - 25.0) / 25.0)) * 40)) / 2
when (TowQty > 0 and SvcQty = 0) then ((1 - ((Acc.AvgTowInv - 50.0) / 50.0)) * 40)
when (TowQty = 0 and SvcQty > 0) then ((1 - ((Acc.AvgSvcInv - 25.0) / 25.0)) * 40)
when (TowQty = 0 and SvcQty = 0) then 0

Would like the Solution in R Programming Language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using nested `ifelse`, you can use `dplyr::case_when()`.

```
require(tidyverse)

TowQty <- c(2,3,4,5,9,0,0,0,4)
SvcQty<- c(4,8,3,4,2,0,4,0,2)
Acc.AvgTowInv<- c(20,25,65,45,67,0,0,0,76)
Acc.AvgSvcInv<-c(25,32,45,53,23,0,26,0,43)

data.frame <- data.frame(TowQty , SvcQty, Acc.AvgTowInv, 
                         Acc.AvgSvcInv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data.frame %>% 
  mutate(newCalc = case_when(
    #Con. 1.
    TowQty > 0 & SvcQty > 0  ~ 
      (((1 - ((Acc.AvgTowInv - 50) / 50)) * 40) +
         ((1 - ((Acc.AvgSvcInv - 25) / 25.0)) * 40)) / 2, 
    #Con. 2
    TowQty > 0 & SvcQty == 0 ~ 
      (1 - ((Acc.AvgTowInv - 50) / 50)) * 40, 
    #Con. 3
    TowQty == 0 & SvcQty > 0 ~ (1 - ((Acc.AvgSvcInv - 25) / 25)) * 40, 
    #Con. 4 
    TowQty == 0 & SvcQty == 0 ~ 0 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a series of ifelse statements as follows:

```
a <- c(1,2,0,0)
b <- c(3,0,2,0)
c <- c(0,10,11,12)
d <- c(0,11,12,13)

data.frame <- data.frame(a , b, c, d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data.frame$nc <- with(data.frame, 
                  ifelse(a > 0 & b >0, c+3, 
                         ifelse(a > 0 & b==0, c+4,
                                ifelse(a==0 & b>0, c+5,
                                       ifelse(a==0 & b==0, 0, 0))))) 

data.frame

  a b  c  d nc
1 1 3  0  0  3
2 2 0 10 11 14
3 0 2 11 12 16
4 0 0 12 13  0
```